# The third way to load Dynamic-Link Libraries? Pin

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Now I can load Dynamic-Link Libraries with static load(include the necessary headers, and use #pragma comment (lib, "xxx")) and dynamic load(with function LoadLibrary or LoadLibraryEx).

Some companies ask the other ways to load Dynamic-Link Libraries in their interview.

But I wonder whether exists other ways to load the Dynamic-Link Libraries?

Comment: may be delay load is mentioned? as for me, this is sort of static link.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's sort of static link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "loading" is a bit vague. A DLL never gets "loaded". The term "dynamically loaded library" is from 16-bit Windows era. Today, contents of a DLL is mapped into the memory using paging. So if they mean copying it's contents to memory by loading, you can even "load" a DLL by reading it directly.

If they mean calling their functions, you can also do that "without" loading the DLL, for instance by using `rundll32.exe` (which maps the DLL into it's own process space, not yours).

And you can of course always imitate what `LoadLibrary` does by initializing function pointers  by analyzing DLL's PE structure, calling `DllMain()` and scanning it's export table.

Comment: Aha, maybe the rundll32.exe what you said is the third way.
Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 3):

There's a terminological mix-up in your question. DLL stands for "*dynamic* link library". They are always loaded *dynamically*, as the name suggests. They cannot be loaded statically. The term "static" is usually used in connection with *static* libraries, i.e. libraries that are not DLLs at all.

A DLL can be loaded *explicitly* by using `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` functions (sometimes called "run-time linking" or "manual linking") or *implicitly* by linking so called *import library* into your program and declaring functions in conventional way (sometimes called "load-time linking" or "automatic linking"). The latter method has two varieties: *pre-load* and *delay-load*. Pre-loaded DLLs are loaded instantly and unconditionally at the start of the program. Delay-loaded DLLs are loaded when (if) they are first used.

So, in this terms, there are still only two major ways to load a DLL: explicit and implicit. The latter load method just happens to have two sub-varieties. Some people might prefer to interpret this hierarchical classification as a flat one, ending up with three linking/loading methods.

BTW, implicit linking is achieved, again, by linking the import library into your program. "Including headers" by itself will not do it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Hey, I have update my question accrording to your point.

Answer (score 1):

One another way is to [Delay-Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx) them which is kind of like static-link but the dll is not loaded until you actually call a function residing in it

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I'm confused Delay-Load still belongs to the two ways(static load and dynamic load).

Delay-Load, as you said should be dynamic load.
Am I right?